# XPath 2 expressions interfering with each other

Tags: logic, set-theory

I have a XML like this:

```
  <Values>
    <Value AttributeID="asset.extension">pdf</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="asset.size">10326</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="ATTR_AssetPush_Webshop">1</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="asset.format">PDF (Portable Document Format application)</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="asset.mime-type">application/pdf</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="asset.filename">filename.pdf</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="asset.uploaded">2018-01-10 17:05:39</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="ATTR_Verwendungsort" Derived="true">WebShop,</Value>
  </Values>
```

I have 2 (or more) XPath-expressions like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/STEP-ProductInformation/Assets/Asset/Values/Value[not(@AttributeID='asset.mime-type')]" />
<xsl:template match="/STEP-ProductInformation/Assets/Asset/Values/Value[not(@AttributeID='asset.size')]" />
```

For some reason though, If I have 2 of them together, all information are being stripped. If I use only 1 expressoin, I get my desired output. Can't I use 2 expressions like this?

I also tried combining them like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/STEP-ProductInformation/Assets/Asset/Values/Value[not(@AttributeID='asset.mime-type') and (@AttributeID='asset.size')]" />
```

But that didn't do it, either.

The desired output would be like this:

```
  <Values>
    <Value AttributeID="asset.size">10326</Value>
    <Value AttributeID="asset.mime-type">application/pdf</Value>
  </Values>
```

Comment: So what would be the desired output?

Comment: You probably want to change the condition to `[not(@AttributeID='asset.mime-type') and not(@AttributeID='asset.size')]` or maybe `[not(@AttributeID='asset.mime-type' or @AttributeID='asset.size')]`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen added the desired output

Comment: @TimC works like a charme. Feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think in XSLT 2/3 you could express it as

```
<xsl:template match="Values/Value[not(@AttributeID = ('asset.mime-type', 'asset.size'))]"/>
```

In XSLT/XPath 1.0 you would need `Values/Value[not(@AttributeID = 'asset.mime-type' or @AttributeID = 'asset.size')]`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <xsl:template match="/STEP-ProductInformation/Assets/Asset/Values
>                                                /Value[not(@AttributeID='asset.mime-type')]" />
> <xsl:template match="/STEP-ProductInformation/Assets/Asset/Values
>                                                /Value[not(@AttributeID='asset.size')]" />
> ```

**This is a logical error -- has nothing to do with XPath**.

**It is like saying**:

1. *From all days of the week I will work only on Mondays*
2. *From the days selected above I will work only on Tuesdays*

The first statement above selects only Mondays. The 2nd statement selects all Tuesdays from these Mondays -- that is the empty set.

**A correct statement**:

*From all days of the week I will work only on **Mondays or Tuesdays***